# Why doesn't my JComboBox's ComboBoxModel ever call seSelectedItem()?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have 2 combo boxes in my swing application - In the code below you'll see elements of Spring as I'm using Spring with it too.  I can't remove spring or the app would stop working without a lot of refactoring work to take up the place of Spring so please don't ask that.  At default start of the application, upon going into the dialog box with the combo boxes, they should show no selection and if you click into the box to open to show the options, there's only one option ("Add...").

The problem is that upon clicking "Add...", the options close but the selection is never replaced.  I thought maybe I needed to add an ActionListener but the ActionListener(which just displays a Message Option Pane with the selection) does not seem to do anything - no message box is shown.  I originally started custom implementing my own ComboBoxModel but then changed it to extending from DefaultComboBoxModel and overriding the methods that need to be different like getElementAt and getSize and such.  getSelectionItem works swimmingly though in my original model (extending default combo box model, I've removed get and set Selection Item as the default class takes care of that for me or so I thought).

What could I be doing wrong or missing?  Here's the code:

```
@Component
 public class WordInstancePartOfSpeechComboBoxModel extends DefaultComboBoxModel<PartOfSpeech> implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2509351721137099113L;
    private static final Logger msObjLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WordInstancePartOfSpeechComboBoxModel.class);

    private List<PartOfSpeech> mLstModel;

    @Autowired
    private WordInstancePartOfSpeechDialogController mObjDialogController;

    protected WordInstancePartOfSpeechDialogController getDialogController()
    {
        return(mObjDialogController);
    }

    public PartOfSpeech getElementAt(final int iIndex)
    {
        if(iIndex > 0)
            return(getModel().get(iIndex - 1));
        else if(iIndex == 0)
            return(new PartOfSpeech("Add..."));
        else
            return(null);
    }

    protected List<PartOfSpeech> getModel()
    {
        try
            {
            if(mLstModel == null)
                mLstModel = getDialogController().listPartOfSpeeches();
            }
        catch(SQLException objException)
            {
            msObjLogger.error("Error retrieving list of Parts of Speech...", objException);
            mLstModel = new ArrayList<PartOfSpeech>();
            }

        return(mLstModel);
    }

    public int getSize()
    {
        return(getModel().size() + 1);
    }
}
```

and the code from my Spring configuration class to implement the JComboBox:

```
if(mCboWordInstancePartOfSpeech == null)
    {
    mCboWordInstancePartOfSpeech = new JComboBox<PartOfSpeech>(getWordInstancePartOfSpeechComboBoxModel());

    mCboWordInstancePartOfSpeech.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder());
    mCboWordInstancePartOfSpeech.setFont(getDefaultFont());
    mCboWordInstancePartOfSpeech.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {   
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent objActionEvent)
        {
            JComboBox<PartOfSpeech> cbo = ((JComboBox<PartOfSpeech>)(objActionEvent.getSource()));

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The selected item is" + cbo.getSelectedIndex(), "Success!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    });
    }

return(mCboWordInstancePartOfSpeech);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - I needed to override .equals() in the class which was being served by the Combo Box.  It doesn't make sense because I never see the code executing to call equals and my code just uses indexOf and get both from list or at least collections both which doesn't need equals but for anyone else - check the equals and put one in and maybe it'll work like a boss again!